# Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25. Telnet says 220 localhost ESMTP server ready

Tags: xampp, jakarta-mail, telnet, symantec

I am using XAMPP for deploying my java application in tomcat and also using mercury mail to send emails. Now i am just testing my application with a small java program using java mail API and mercury email. I have done the necessary configuration in Mercury to setup localhost. Now when running the java program..its says

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1962)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
```

While my XAMPP Mercury Server is up and running with following port numbers

```
25, 79, 105 , 106, 110, 143, 2224
```

I also tested telnet command...result is as follows..

```
telnet localhost 25
220 localhost ESMTP server ready.
```

Now I'm stuck. Since i am working from my university lab and Symantec End Point Protection is installed on the systems so i cant even check if the Firewall is causing any problems....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly Symantec End Point Protection that is causing the problem.  Probably your university doesn't want you running your own mail server.